# Make shape stick to chart when moved

Tags: excel, vba

I tried grouping the shape to the chart but then again, i have to select the chart and the shapes to make them movable.

Isn't there any easier way to make any shape added really stick to the chart. In some other file I have the shape not only stick when moved but also can't get out of the chart frame.

Using excel 2016, would prefer a vba free solution. It's a waterfall graph if that makes any difference.

Thank you

Theres no good answer, Im closing this sorry

Comment: Did you add the shape while the graph was selected?

Answer (score 1):

When adding shapes that you want to stay with a chart, you must:

- Select the chart
- Choose the shape to insert
- Draw your shape inside the chart area

To add and existing shape to the chart

- Select the shape
- Use Cut on the shape
- Select the chart
- Use Paste on the chart

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that. I think it doesn't work with new graphs from excel 2016. In fact, many features with new graphs such as waterfall are disabled with 2016( saving as a template).

Answer (score 0):

With the shape selected, use the Shape Format tab and the 'Group' function in the Arrange menu of the tab. Need to select the chart as well

Answer (score 0):

Michael Russo's answer is correct. Either create the shape while the chart is selected, or cut the shape, select the chart, and then paste it, and it will paste *into* the chart. After you've inserted the shape into the chart, you can cut or copy the entire chart and it takes the shape with it. You can even copy the chart and paste the image of it into another Office document.

Answer (score 0):

People facing problem making shape/text stick to the chart with newer versions of Excel (2016 and above), try inserting a shape while the chart is already selected. Then select both the chart and the shape together by pressing Ctrl button.

After doing this, go to Shape Format and click Group->Group. It makes them stick together, worked for me. One flaw with this function I experienced is that I couldn't do this for more than one element (text/shape) with the chart.